# Email Automation from Outlook Express using JACOB.jar with Java

Tags: java, email, outlook

I have to automate emails from Outlook Express Client using Java. Below are the requirements:

1. Format the RichText Email using predefined template(Provided in Excel)
2. Send the email to dedicated Receiver Email Id
3. Send the reminder email by keeping the history of previous email

I was able to achieve all the mentioned requirements for Lotus Mail Email Client by using Notes.jar.

As I can not use JavaMail to directly send email to Email Server and Read due to Organization's Policy. So I have to go with automation from Email Client only.

I have heard about JACOB.jar. Can anyone please share if above all mentioned requirements be achieved with JACOB.jar? It would be really a great help.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of JACOB jar ?

Comment: No,I haven't gone through the documentation yet.Just got the info from Google that JACOB can be used to read the email from Outlook using java.

Comment: Hi Suresh,                                                                                                            Please share if you have any link.

Comment: Here you go : http://danadler.com/jacob/

Comment: The documentation should *always* be your first port of call.